# Changing my ubuntu version from one to another

Tags: 14.04

I have just installed the EDUBUNTU , but I was not meant to download that type of version.As I want my operating system to be meant for the business purpose only but not for the applications meant for children.So please tell me the solution about this , so I can change to another ubuntu type directly from this operating system version.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a re-installation of the version you do want to use (Ubuntu, kUbuntu etc). If you added personal documents make a backup of those documents and restore them after you are done.

> so I can change to another ubuntu type directly from this operating system version

In that case this ...

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

will ADD the Ubuntu desktop to your system.

This ...

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
```

will ADD the kUbuntu desktop to your system. The same applies for other versions (just got to change the to install package to what you want).

If you want to remove edubuntu you can do that with ...

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge edubuntu* 
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

The last command will remove packages that are no longer needed but did not get removed. I would suggest doing this after you confirm the newly added desktop is working.

But because it is important to make a backup before doing this I would advice to do a re-installation. It is the easiest and probably quickest method to get back up and running.